# Function in event just one time

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I have the following code:

```
<input id="inputID1" value="click me" type="button" />
<input id="inputID2" value="click me again!" type="button" />
```

the script:

```
$("#inputID1").click(function()
                     {alert("inputID1 click");
                     $("#inputID2").click(function()
                                  {funcWaitToInput();
                                  return;});
                     }
                    );
function funcWaitToInput()
{alert("just one time");}
```

I mean that
after `inputID1` clicked,
wait to `inputID2` cliked and  run `funcWaitToInput()` function in the first `inputID2` click,

but, every time I press `inputID2` button function occurs again
I want that after `inputID1` clicking  is waiting to clicking on the `inputID2`, and the `funcWaitToInput()` function run only the first click,

I was looking for how to do it and not found.

The code in **jsfiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/bniya_dev/UfwHF/

Answer (score 1):

That's what jQuery's [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) method is for:

```
$("#inputID1").click(function() {
    alert("inputID1 click");
    $("#inputID2").one('click', function() {
        alert("just one time");
    });
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UfwHF/2/

Comment: you still need the initial `alert`.

Answer (score 0):

I almost understand your question, I think:

```
$("#inputID1").click(function(){
    alert("inputID1 click");
    $("#inputID2").bind('click',funcWaitToInput);
});

function funcWaitToInput() {
    alert("just one time");
    $("#inputID2").unbind('click',funcWaitToInput);
};
```

Comment: Ah, @JosephSilber's answer does a more concise version of the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Add one line to your function.

```
function funcWaitToInput()
{alert("just one time");
 $('#inputID2').attr('onclick','').unbind('click');
}
```